# Typescript, tagged actions and array of reducers

Tags: typescript

I'm using typescript and working on code that borrows heavily from redux way of work, `(action, state) => state`.

Trying really hard to use typescript in the strictest way possible. My issue is best explained with the example.

First, I have an enum describing the types of actions:

```
enum Tags {
  TAG_A = 'tagA',
  TAG_B = 'tagB'
}
```

next I define unique fields of every type:

```
type Payload = {
  [Tags.TAG_A]: {
    foo: string;
  },
  [Tags.TAG_B]: {
    bar: number;
  }
}
```

now I define my action types:

```
type Action<T extends Tags> = {
  type: T;
  id: string;
  moreCommonField: boolean;
} & Payload[T];

type Actions = { [T in Tags]: Action<T> }[Tags]
```

and now the reducer:

```
type State = { somevar: string }; //doesnt matter, example

const reducer = (action: Actions, state: State): State => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case Tags.TAG_A:
      action.foo; /* correct type, yay */
      break;
    case Tags.TAG_B:
      action.bar; /* correct type, yay */
      break;
  }
  return {...state};
}
```

So far, everything is great!

But in the real world, I have lots and lots of action, and my `switch` looks kinda ugly.

so I tried this:

```
const minireducers: { [K in Tags]: (action: Action<K>, state: State) => State } = {
  [Tags.TAG_A]: (action, state) => {
    // we have correct type of action here, big benefit
    return {...state};
  },
  [Tags.TAG_B]: (action, state) => ({...state})
}
```

This is great because most "minireducers" are just oneliners. This also has the benefit of forcing me to not forget to handle any actions I might add later.

However, when I try to write the actual reducer for this:

```
const reducer2 = (action: Actions, state: State) => {
  const minireducer = minireducers[action.type]; 
  const newState = minireducer(action, state); //error
  return newState;
}
```

---

The error here is clear to me, `action.type` isn't narrowed to any specific type, so `minireducer` can be many things, and it's type is a union, you can't call a union. With casting it will obviously work, but I would like a solution that doesn't require casting. Even just as a thought experiment.

Anyone has any idea to a solution that is as type safe as possible and that would allow me to split my reducer into smaller reducers like in the example?

You don't have to stick to my type definitions or structure, But again, type safety and good type inference is the goal here.

[link to playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=enum%20Tags%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20TAG_A%20%3D%20'tagA'%2C%0D%0A%20%20TAG_B%20%3D%20'tagB'%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Payload%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5BTags.TAG_A%5D%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%5BTags.TAG_B%5D%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Action%3CT%20extends%20Tags%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20type%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%20%20id%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20moreCommonField%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D%20%26%20Payload%5BT%5D%3B%0D%0Atype%20Actions%20%3D%20%7B%20%5BT%20in%20Tags%5D%3A%20Action%3CT%3E%20%7D%5BTags%5D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20State%20%3D%20%7B%20somevar%3A%20string%20%7D%3B%20%2F%2Fdoesnt%20matter%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20reducer%20%3D%20(action%3A%20Actions%2C%20state%3A%20State)%3A%20State%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20switch%20(action.type)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20case%20Tags.TAG_A%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20action.foo%3B%20%2F%2Fcorrect%20type%2C%20yay%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20break%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20case%20Tags.TAG_B%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20action.bar%3B%20%2F%2Fcorrect%20type%2C%20yay%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20break%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20return%20%7B...state%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F*%20now%20trying%20to%20break%20this%20*%2F%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20minireducers%3A%20%7B%20%5BK%20in%20Tags%5D%3A%20(action%3A%20Action%3CK%3E%2C%20state%3A%20State)%20%3D%3E%20State%20%7D%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5BTags.TAG_A%5D%3A%20(action%2C%20state)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20we%20have%20correct%20type%20of%20action%20here%2C%20big%20benfit%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B...state%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%5BTags.TAG_B%5D%3A%20(action%2C%20state)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B...state%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20reducer2%20%3D%20(action%3A%20Actions%2C%20state%3A%20State)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20const%20minireducer%20%3D%20minireducers%5Baction.type%5D%3B%20%0D%0A%20%20const%20newState%20%3D%20minireducer(action%2C%20state)%3B%20%2F%2Ferror%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2Fwith%20casting%20it's%20fine%0D%0A%20%20const%20minireducer2%20%3D%20minireducers%5Baction.type%5D%20as%20(action%3A%20Actions%2C%20state%3A%20State)%20%3D%3E%20State%3B%0D%0A%20%20const%20newState2%20%3D%20minireducer2(action%2C%20state)%20%0D%0A%20%20return%20newState2%3B%0D%0A%7D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `minireducer` will be a union of all signatures, and the signature is not callable.

There is [feature](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29011) for typescript `3.3` to relax this restriction but your code will not work as that will expect the first argument to be an intersection of all arguments in the signature union.

One solution, if you don't mind an extra function call is to use an extra function, that will put the compiler to rest that the object will have the correct signature:

```
const reducer2 = (action: Actions, state: State) => {
    // r must have a property K that is a function taking Action<K> 
    function call<K extends Tags>(o: Action<K>, r: Record<K, (action: Action<K>, state: State) => State>, state: State) {
        r[o.type](o, state); // r[o.type] is  (action: Action<K>, state: State) => State which is callable with an Action<K> 
    }
    const newState = call(action, minireducers, state);
    return newState;
}
```

Comment: ok, when checking, this doesn't work with `strictFunctionTypes` , and I prefer not to disable any strict flags. (I prefer casting to `any` locally)

Like I wrote, I'm interested in a solution even purely from a theoretical point of view, trying to understand if something like this is possible to write with static types. it might just not be possible.

If you come up with a different solution it would be great if you can share it, I'm kinda lost. removed acceptance for nowm if nobody will answer in a day or two will accept yours. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @AviadHadad wops, I thought I had it turned on ...sorry